# Laravel Route not defined for registercontroller

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I inherited a project.  I saw that there was a `app/Http/Controller/Auth/RegisterController.php`, but going to the websites `/register` gave me a 404 error.  So I added this line to `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create')->name('register.create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
```

And now I can go to the url `/register` and sign up a new user without any issues.

I went into `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` and added the line

`Don't have an account? <a href="{{route('register.create')}}">Sign up</a>`

But this gave me an error `Route [register.create] not defined. View(.. path to login.blade.php`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you verify that /register isn't under middleware ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

The reason why you it's returning a `404` is because when you manually register the registration routes and you do it before the `Auth::routes` which registers one with the same key that overwrites yours. Hence why it's working if you move them after the `Auth::routes`.

What you could do is disable the register routes from the Auth facade:

```php
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create')->name('register.create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');

Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

If you plan on using Laravel's default registration system, you simply have to remove your manually registered routes and create the respective views and you can access the route with `route('register');`.

You can also check the other available routes generated by the Auth facade with `php artisan route:list`.

### Note

Also, you do not need to group them in the `web` middleware when adding routes in `routes/web.php` because they are automatically in the middleware by the `RouteServiceProvider`.

```php
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem.  I made a guess changed this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    ... other code ...
    Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create')->name('register.create');
    Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');

    Auth::routes();
    ... other code ...
});
```

To this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    ... other code ...

    Auth::routes();
    ... other code ...
});
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create')->name('register.create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
```

And it worked.  NOt sure if this is the right way to do it though